# React Typescript i18n : i18next::translator: missingKey en translation

Tags: reactjs, i18next

I have been trying to use 'backend' option to load my translations but seeing 'missing_key' for all the translations. Attached are the screenshots of my code. Any help will be appreciated.

[image]

[image: <!-----index.tsx------>]

[image: <!----Error----->]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if the keys in your translation files match each other. They must be identical, example:

en/translation.json

```json
{
  "name": "Name"
}
```

fr/translation.json

```json
{
  "name": "Nom"
}
```

Comment: the keys are exactly the same. This was working earlier when I used namespaces. But it started giving errors when I switched to 'backend' option

Comment: check if you added .use(Backend)? I don't see it in your screenshot

Comment: also, your translations should be located inside public/locales, respectively, loadPath should also be changed to /locales/{{lng}}/translation.json

Comment: use(HttpApi) is my backend. Just updated the screenshot.

Comment: moving my translations to public folder actually worked! thank you! is it always supposed to be in public folder? I thought it doesn't matter where I keep my translations?